# NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am new to scala and I am trying to create a mixed project with Scala and Java.
However I am facing some issues when I run the test code. When I run the test, I am getting an error

[image: []]

and my pom.xml as follows:

```
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.12.2</scala.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My code as follows:

```
class BptConsumer {

def consumeLogevent(): Unit ={
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("PVStatistics");
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(5));

  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "172.20.13.196:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "group.id" -> "1",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
  )

  val topics = Array("fd-blogs-tst")

  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
  )
  /*val rdd = stream.transform(x=>RDD[String]);*/
  val lines = stream.map(record => (record.key,record.value))

  lines.print();
  ssc.start();
  ssc.awaitTermination();
}
}
```

Could someone help me out in finding the issue?

Answer (score 21):

You're using Scala 2.12.2 with Spark libraries that are built with Scala 2.11. Change your Scala version to a 2.11 release:

```
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.11</scala.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: This worked for me, as well, but I'm a little unclear on why this works. The Spark libraries may have been built with 2.11, but, if they're self-contained JARs, then shouldn't they be able to just run, regardless of what version of Scala I am using in my own project?

Comment: You are the man! I was banging my head against a wall trying to upgrade to the newest Scala, now I know why... Glad I could get to it 2.11 at least

Comment: I got the same issue when I added dependency on the library compiled with scala 2.12 compiler.

Comment: Hi, I just ran into the same error after installing PySpark 3.0. The env tab on SparkUI says Java vr; 1.8.0_211, and Scala vr: 2.12.10. How can I fix the compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

module dependencies caotains the scala-2.11.jars using exclusion in maven to clean