# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class for gradle JUNIT test

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I have a scala application with a build.gradle (using gradleVersion 4.4.1). I am using the JUnit Framework. The dependency and test task sections of my gradle.build is below

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.12:2.6.9'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.8'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:3.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

When I run gradle test

> Task :test FAILED

```
com.someOrg.gdpschemautils.JsonToSchemaSpec > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

1 test completed, 1 failed

When I run gradle test --debug

```
19:20:21.303 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] com.someOrg.gdpschemautils.JsonToSchemaSpec > initializationError FAILED
19:20:21.303 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
19:20:21.303 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.time.Units.<init>(Units.scala:33)
19:20:21.304 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.time.Days$.<init>(Units.scala:293)
19:20:21.304 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.time.Days$.<clinit>(Units.scala)
19:20:21.304 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.time.Span$.<init>(Span.scala:584)
19:20:21.304 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.time.Span$.<clinit>(Span.scala)
19:20:21.304 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.Suite$.<init>(Suite.scala:1399)
19:20:21.304 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.scalatest.Suite$.<clinit>(Suite.scala)
```

Below is The App Structure.

```
.
├── README.md
├── build.gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── settings.gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── src
  └──  main
    └──  scala
       └── com
           └── someOrg
               └── gdpschemautils
                    ├── Config
                    ├── DataSourcePathException
                    ├── JsonToSchema
                    ├── ObjectToJsonSchema
                    ├── SchemaConverter
                    ├── SchemaToJson

  └── test
    └── resources
        ├── testJsonSchema.json

    └── scala
       └── com
           └── someOrg
               └── gdpschemautils
                    ├── JsonToSchemaSpec
```

It seems scala classes are not available for the unit tests at run time, I have added testCompile for the scala-library as well in my dependencies and I still get the same error. None of my unit tests will run, rather JsonToSchemaSpec or others.

Answer (score 1):

Such things usually happen when you accidentally mix different incompatible versions of scala/spark/scaletest. See this for example [NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387404/noclassdeffounderror-scala-productclass)

Comment: i posted my dependencies above. where do you see incompatible versions? Thank you for answering

Comment: @bhajer I'm not insisting they are definitely incompatible. I mean that the first thing I would try is to change the versions (all together). Just try "all 2.12" or "all 2.13".