# Unable to run amazon deequ examples locally

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-deequ

I am trying to run and test amazon deequ library locally but am repeatedly getting the class not found error for various examples. exact error

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
  at com.amazon.deequ.profiles.ColumnProfilerRunBuilderFileOutputOptions.<init>(ColumnProfilerRunner.scala:31)
  at com.amazon.deequ.profiles.ColumnProfilerRunBuilder.run(ColumnProfilerRunBuilder.scala:174)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
  ... 49 more
```

or

```
val suggestionResult = ConstraintSuggestionRunner().onData(input).addConstraintRules(Rules.DEFAULT).run()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
  at com.amazon.deequ.suggestions.rules.CompleteIfCompleteRule.<init>(CompleteIfCompleteRule.scala:25)
  at com.amazon.deequ.suggestions.Rules$.<init>(ConstraintSuggestionRunner.scala:33)
  at com.amazon.deequ.suggestions.Rules$.<clinit>(ConstraintSuggestionRunner.scala)
  ... 49 elided
```

the code i followed is the one given in the examples I used spark-submit --class  --packages com.amazon.deequ:deequ:1.0.4

i also tried using spark-shell --jars  and tried running lines one by one but still getting same result

Comment: what is the Spark version?

Comment: I am using spark version 3.0.0-preview2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Deequ that you're using doesn't work with Spark 3.0 that is compiled with Scala 2.12, so it's causing this error (as pointed by Philipp).  So you have two possible solutions:

1. Use Spark 2.4.x that is compatible with Deequ 1.0.4
2. Compile Deequ from [sources](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ) with following command: `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pscala-2.12 -Pspark-3.0`, and then you can use it with spark-shell as: `bin/spark-shell --jars <path-to-deequ-checkout>/target/deequ_2.12-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (unfortunately we can't use `--packages` because of build problem in Maven)

P.S. It's better to grab latest Spark -> 3.0.1 - preview version was released too long ago

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to deequ but likely caused by a wrong Scala version. deequ supports Scala 2.11 only at the moment. Please make sure you are using the correct version.

See this answer for more details [NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387404/noclassdeffounderror-scala-productclass/44387752).

Comment: I am using the scala 2.11.11 but still it shows the same error

Comment: Please make sure to use a deequ-compatible Spark version (2.4.x, for example) like Alex pointed out in his answer.